# How to represent join queries in Django?

Tags: django, database

How do we present sql query like this one in django?

```
select * from question LEFT JOIN (select * from question_solved where username = 'ashu'

) AS result on question.q_id = result.q_id
```

I tried to perform query separately,

q = question_solved.objects.filter(username='ashu')

y = Question.objects.filter(q__q_id = Question.q_id)

But it is giving me error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'q' into field. Choices are: q_answer, q_content, q_id, q_submission, q_tags, q_title, q_type
```

my model file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    q_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    #q_difficulty = models.IntegerField()
    q_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    q_content = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    q_type = models.IntegerField()
    q_answer = models.FloatField()
    q_submission = models.IntegerField()
    q_tags = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class question_solved(models.Model):
    q_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Query will produce result like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your models file

Comment: Ugh, why are you prefixing everything with `q_` in your `Question` model? I'd push back hard on that during code review.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to relate models .
From what I understood you want to get all the questions solved by username `ashu`.

In your current state of models you can do this like:

First get a list of `q_id` values that are in the table for username `ashu`. you can do that using [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
quest=question_solved.objects.filter(username='ashu').values_list('q_id',flat=True)
```

Then from the `Question` table filter the objects with `q_id` in the list obtained from previous query.

```
solved_questions=Question.objects.filter(q_id__in=quest)
```

You can get all the question with [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all)

```
all_questions = Question.objects.all()
```

and if you want you can have 2 separate queryset one which is a list of question solved by 'ashu`and other which is not solved by`ashu`.

```
unsolved_questions=Question.objects.exclude(q_id__in=quest).
```

Comment: Actually i'm the trying to get all the questions and for the questions for which user 'ashu' has solved the question, values of join column username and q_id will be displayed otherwise it will show null.

Comment: please see the image. I want my result as in the image.i have just now added the image. Query is working fine in sql-shell but i'm not able to use it in django.

Comment: @AshutoshAgarwal, I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying that, instead of a `QuerySet` (basically an ordered collection of objects), you want something like a table of primitive values? If so, why? How are you using this data? You can probably do the same thing with a `QuerySet`, and `QuerySet`s are fundamental to queries against Django's ORM.

Comment: @Chris Actually i want to retrieve all the questions. And the question which student has already solved i want to highlight them. If i separately query solved and unsolved question and then check one by one if user has done it or not it will increase time. So i want to retrieve all the questions in an order and for the question which has been solved, values of q_id2 and username will not be null. I can use that to show questions in one go.

Comment: Currently I have only 2 question in question table and 2 users in user table. and 2 entries 1 for user1 and other for user2 in question_solved table.

Comment: @AshutoshAgarwal I think what you are asking will take more time because for each question you will check if the value of the `q_id` and `username` is null or not. But if you take 2 different `queryset` you will not have to perform that kind of check. Because for each of the 2 `queryset` you will know if the user has solved it or not.

Comment: @sasuke  I want to display the questions in the order of id's. Using 2 queryset will create section. And if I use 2 queryset then to display them in an order will take time.